# Hamiltonian of a 3-level system with Zeeman sub-levels

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, atomic-physics, hamiltonian-formalism

I'm trying to write the Hamiltonian for Rb87 D1 ($1/2S \rightarrow 1/2P$) transition with $\Lambda$ scheme- i.e one Laser is resonant with $F=1 \rightarrow F'=2$ and another with $F=2 \rightarrow F'=2$ both with $\sigma^+$ polarization (so only transitions with $\Delta m_F = +1$ are possible) as depicted in the image 
[image].

Assuming some constant magnetic field in the $\hat{Z}$ direction, the two ground states have 5+3=8 zeeman sublevels and the excited level has 5 zeeman sublevels, so we have now a 13-level system but only 2 laser fields.
 Is there any intuitive way to write a time-independent Hamiltonian for this? 
For a closed 3-level system with atom-Hamiltonian: $H_{0} = 
\hbar \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \omega_2  & 0\\
0 & 0 & \omega_3
\end{pmatrix}$, with two resonant fields of frequencies $\omega_{L1}$ , $\omega_{L2}$ and under rotating wave approximation,  i managed to write down a very simple rotated frame Hamiltonian;
$H_{RF} = 
\hbar \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \Omega_1 \\
0 & \Delta_1  & \Omega_2\\
\Omega_1^* & \Omega_2^* & \Delta_2
\end{pmatrix}$ where $\Omega_{1/2}$ are the Rabi frequencies and $\Delta_1=\omega_2 - \omega_{L1}+ \omega_{L2}$ , $\Delta_2=\omega_3 - \omega_{L1}$ .
 I wish to write something in similar fashion with 13x13 matrix.

Comment: $H_{\text{RF}}$ should be Hermitian.

Comment: How is it not Hermitian...?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to calculate are elements of the Hamiltonian $H=H_0+H_{B}$, namely $$
\langle FM|H|F'M' \rangle=
\langle FM|H_0|F'M' \rangle
+
\langle FM|H_B|F'M' \rangle,
$$
where $F,M$ denotes energy levels, $H_0$ is Hamiltonian without magnetic field and $H_{B}$ results form the magnetic field. The first term in R.H.S. is already known,
$$
\langle FM| H_0|F'M'\rangle = E_{F}\delta_{FF'}\delta_{MM'}.
$$
The second one is easy to caculate too,
$$
\langle FM| H_B|F'M'\rangle \propto \langle FM| \vec J|F'M'\rangle.
$$

Comment: thanks very much for the reply but I don't understand your answer..  $H_0$ is now a 13x13 matrix with some sort of rotating frame transformation that cancels out(hopefully, but maybe not..) time-dependencies.

Comment: @guy What do you mean by rotating frame transformation?

Comment: What i mean by rotating frame transformation, for example when you have a 2-level Hamiltonian, $H_{0} = 
\hbar \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0  \\
0 & \omega_2  \\
\end{pmatrix}$ coupled with  laser that gives interaction term: $H_{I} = 
\hbar \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \Omega e^{i\omega_{L} t}  \\
\Omega^* e^{-i\omega_{L}t} & 0  \\ \end{pmatrix}$ (with rotating wave approximation). you can transform the hamiltonian with a unitary transformation $U=e^{-i\omega_{L} \ket{2} \bra{2}}$ and get a time-independent Hamiltonian $H_{RF}= 
\hbar \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \Omega  \\ \Omega^* & \delta  \\ \end{pmatrix}$